# Bundling records in MySQL SELECT query, stored as timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

Not sure how to ask this, but let me give you my problem:

I have a table with 50 000 records, in one column (named recorded_at) a timestamp. Now what I would like to have a SQL SELECT query (processed with PHP) that results in an array with the total per days. So the result would look like:

```
$array["2012-01-01"] = 4;
$array["2012-01-02"] = 14;
$array["2012-01-03"] = 45;
$array["2012-01-04"] = 33;
```

And so on...

I could of course loop through 365 days a year and SELECT 365 times, but that seems very inefficient. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(recorded_at)), COUNT(*) totalCOunt
FROM tableName
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(recorded_at))
```

Comment: Thanks Nikos! Looks like it outputs EXACTLY what I needed!